# R markdown heading issue ( R version 3.6.2)

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown, heading

I am having an issue with Rmarkdown (printing PDF files). I updated R to verions 3.6.2 and now R markdown is printing the heading syntax on the PDF files.

The syntax: ### Hello world

is actually shown as " ### Hello world " in the final PDF output.

Any thought on that?

Thanks!

Comment: have you correctly installed miktex? does your code look like `---
output: pdf_document
---

### Hello World
`

Answer (score 0):

I have `tinytex` package and R version 3.6.2. The following chunk works correctly for an `Rmd` document.

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

### Hello world

This is a test.
```